# Windows Gadget AJAX Security Warning

Tags: jquery, ajax, security, windows-desktop-gadgets

I've created a Windows Gadget using JQuery to call the oAuth-Service of Yammer: https://www.yammer.com/oauth/request_token [(API Documentation)](https://www.yammer.com/api_oauth.html)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.yammer.com/oauth/request_token",
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", oAuthHeader)
    },
    success: function() { ... },
    error: function() { ... }
});
```

The sidebar.exe process shows an security alert, because I'm calling an HTTPS address. 
*"This page is accessing information that is not under its control. This poses a security risk. Do you want to continue?"*

There is no HTTP address for this service. Is there a way to avoid this warning?

[image: This page is accessing information that is not under its control. This poses a security risk. Do you want to continue?]

Thank's

**Update 2010-11-28:**
This is my current configuration. Is there anything special?

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\0]
"1001"=dword:00000001
"1004"=dword:00000003
"1200"=dword:00000000
"1201"=dword:00000003
"1206"=dword:00000000
"1207"=dword:00000000
"1208"=dword:00000000
"1209"=dword:00000000
"120A"=dword:00000003
"120B"=dword:00000000
"1400"=dword:00000000
"1402"=dword:00000000
"1405"=dword:00000000
"1406"=dword:00000001
"1407"=dword:00000000
"1408"=dword:00000000
"1409"=dword:00000003
"1601"=dword:00000000
"1604"=dword:00000000
"1605"=dword:00000000
"1606"=dword:00000000
"1607"=dword:00000000
"1608"=dword:00000000
"1609"=dword:00000001
"160A"=dword:00000000
"1802"=dword:00000000
"1803"=dword:00000000
"1804"=dword:00000000
"1805"=dword:00000000
"1806"=dword:00000000
"1807"=dword:00000000
"1808"=dword:00000000
"1809"=dword:00000003
"180A"=dword:00000000
"180C"=dword:00000000
"180D"=dword:00000000
"180E"=dword:00000000
"180F"=dword:00000000
"1A00"=dword:00000000
"1A02"=dword:00000000
"1A03"=dword:00000000
"1A04"=dword:00000000
"1A05"=dword:00000000
"1A06"=dword:00000000
"1A10"=dword:00000000
"1C00"=dword:00020000
"2000"=dword:00000000
"2005"=dword:00000000
"2100"=dword:00000000
"2101"=dword:00000003
"2102"=dword:00000000
"2103"=dword:00000000
"2104"=dword:00000000
"2105"=dword:00000000
"2106"=dword:00000000
"2200"=dword:00000000
"2201"=dword:00000000
"2300"=dword:00000001
"2301"=dword:00000003
"2400"=dword:00000000
"2401"=dword:00000000
"2402"=dword:00000000
"2500"=dword:00000003
"2600"=dword:00000000
"2700"=dword:00000003
"CurrentLevel"=dword:00000000
"Description"="Your computer"
"DisplayName"="Computer"
"Flags"=dword:00000021
"Icon"="shell32.dll#0016"
"LowIcon"="inetcpl.cpl#005422"
"PMDisplayName"="Computer [Protected Mode]"
"2004"=dword:00000003
"2007"=dword:00000003
"2001"=dword:00000003
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\0]
"1001"=dword:00000000
"1004"=dword:00000000
"1200"=dword:00000000
"1201"=dword:00000001
"1206"=dword:00000000
"1207"=dword:00000000
"1208"=dword:00000000
"1209"=dword:00000000
"120A"=dword:00000000
"120B"=dword:00000000
"1400"=dword:00000000
"1402"=dword:00000000
"1405"=dword:00000000
"1406"=dword:00000000
"1407"=dword:00000000
"1408"=dword:00000000
"1409"=dword:00000003
"1601"=dword:00000000
"1604"=dword:00000000
"1605"=dword:00000000
"1606"=dword:00000000
"1607"=dword:00000000
"1608"=dword:00000000
"1609"=dword:00000001
"160A"=dword:00000000
"1802"=dword:00000000
"1803"=dword:00000000
"1804"=dword:00000000
"1805"=dword:00000000
"1806"=dword:00000000
"1807"=dword:00000000
"1808"=dword:00000000
"1809"=dword:00000003
"180A"=dword:00000000
"180C"=dword:00000000
"180D"=dword:00000000
"180E"=dword:00000000
"180F"=dword:00000000
"1A00"=dword:00000000
"1A02"=dword:00000000
"1A03"=dword:00000000
"1A04"=dword:00000000
"1A05"=dword:00000000
"1A06"=dword:00000000
"1A10"=dword:00000000
"1C00"=dword:00020000
"2000"=dword:00000000
"2005"=dword:00000000
"2100"=dword:00000000
"2101"=dword:00000003
"2102"=dword:00000000
"2103"=dword:00000000
"2104"=dword:00000000
"2105"=dword:00000000
"2106"=dword:00000000
"2200"=dword:00000000
"2201"=dword:00000000
"2300"=dword:00000001
"2301"=dword:00000003
"2400"=dword:00000000
"2401"=dword:00000000
"2402"=dword:00000000
"2500"=dword:00000003
"2600"=dword:00000000
"2700"=dword:00000003
"CurrentLevel"=dword:00000000
"Description"="Your computer"
"DisplayName"="Computer"
"Flags"=dword:00000021
"Icon"="shell32.dll#0016"
"LowIcon"="inetcpl.cpl#005422"
"PMDisplayName"="Computer [Protected Mode]"
"2007"=dword:00000003
"2004"=dword:00000003
"2001"=dword:00000003
```

Comment: *https* shouldn't make a difference, I've used it numerous times from a windows desktop gadget.  Have you checked your security settings are at their defaults?

Comment: hey andy E. i never changed the security flags by myself. i used "Reset all zones to there default level" in ie9. my system is 64bit. thanks for your opinion.

Comment: not sure what could be the problem, I'm also running IE9 beta on Windows 7 x64 with the zones at their defaults.  Instead of using `$.ajax`, which defaults to the non-native XMLHttp, you could try the `new XMLHttpRequest()` approach instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've found the problem!

there was an configuration error in the registry! "Reset all zones to there default level" did not modify the 32bit settings.

it's running with the default registry settings of windows 7.